# Unusual Seg Fault: Cannot declare variables outside global?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, global-variables

I've been stuck for a few hours working on a c program that will loop 5 times while the user inputs 5 integers for a linked list.  Somehow I cannot declare variables in my main without getting a segmentation fault in the print function.

My typedef:

```
typedef struct node_{
    int value;
    struct node_* next;
}node;

int y = 0; //If this is made local in main, seg fault
```

My main

```
int main(void)
{
    node *head;
    int x;
    //int y; /*Does not work here*/
    while(y < 5)
    {
        printf("Insert: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        head = insert_top(head, x);
        print(head);
        y ++;
    }
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

My insert function

```
node* insert_top(node* head, int value)
{
    node *newHead;
    newHead = malloc(sizeof(node));

    newHead->value = value;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newHead;
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        newHead->next = head;
        head = newHead;
        return head;
    }
}
```

My print function

```
void print(node* head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d->", head->value);
            head = head->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
```

For some reason, if I set the program to loop until the user inputs a number, say, -1, the program is fine and no problem.  But I cannot declare any other integers (even if they have no use) without getting a seg fault.  Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?  I would like to be led down the path, but not necessarily told the answer.

Comment: Have you tried `int y = 0;` in your `main()`?

Comment: When you declare `y` locally, did you initialize it to zero? (Your commented out version doesn't do so.)

Comment: If I initialize it to zero, it still doesn't work

Comment: I have tested `int y = 0;` in `main()`, it works for me.

Comment: And `node *head = NULL;` too. Guess your uninitialized pointer cause some UB.

Comment: @leeduhem, I just tested it, it works if I initialize it above node, but can you explain why this is??

Comment: Same as uninitialized local variable `y`, the value of your uninitialized local variable `head` could be anything, if it points to some where you cannot access, your program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
node *head = NULL;
int y = 0; /*Does not work here*/
```

Please make above change in `main` and remove global declaration of `y`.